# CSS Opacity 0 vs 0.0001

Tags: css

I noticed on github that they use opacity of 0.0001, rather than 0, on certain elements they want to make transparent.  Why is that?

Answer (score 8):

If you set opacity to **0**, it disappears from the page. But if you set opacity to **0.0001**, it's still on the page (just "very hard to see") and it keep it's functionality (e.g. click etc).

Comment: I tested `opacity:0;` on an `<input type="file" />` and it works fine on chrome. Is this browser specific? element specific?

Comment: Im guessing the same, that it might have to do with compatibility... If I only want to support modern browsers can I just go with `opacity: 0;`?

Comment: when I try this: `opacity: 0.00001` is fully visible in Firefox 88.0.1. `opacity: 0.01` is almost invisible, `opacity: 0.001` is fully visible.